# Generate Java methods from swagger yaml to be used with my own methods

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

```
---
swagger: "2.0"

definitions:
  Result:
    properties:
      data:
        type: string
        description: Some data result

  Payload:
    properties:
      id:
        required: true
        type: integer
      data:
        required: true
        type: string
```

After I have generated the Swagger POJOs I create in a method in a class like this.

```
 public Result sendMessage(int id, String data) throws IOException {
        return some_clazz.go(
                Result.class,
                new Payload().id(id).data(data)
        );
    }
```

The problem is that I have many different definitions and I am pretty much just duplicating the pattern since each of them use the common `some_clazz.go` method (note: some_clazz uses `genetics` hence the first arg). For example:

```
 public AnotherResult sendMessage(int id) throws IOException {
        return some_clazz.go(
                AnotherResult.class,
                new DifferentPayload().id(id)
        );
    }
```

Is there a way for swagger (or something else) to generate classes and methods from my definitions that can be passed to `some_clazz.go`?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but OpenAPI/Swagger does not have the `required` attribute for properties. Instead, add `type: object` and `required: [id, data]` alongside the `properties` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I follow what some_clazz.go does or what it is you want to send to it. 
But to try and answer your question - you can expand swagger-codegen.

In order to do this, you would have to extend the current swagger-codegen by extending DefaultCodegen, or more likely to extend the Codegen you're currently using (SpringCodegen, AbstractJavaCodegen, etc. whatever works for you). In your new codegen class you need to add a new template

```
    public void processOpts() {
        super.processOpts();
        supportingFiles.add(new SupportingFile("someclazzgo.mustache", invokerFolder, "SomeClazzGoImpl.java"));
```

So now the generator will take someclazzgo.mustache and create SomeClazzGoImpl.java according to the template you create. It's up to you to implement that template. You can implement a method for each operation or a class if that's what you need. Perhaps if you give more details as to what you're trying to do I can give more concrete examples (is some_clazz.go called for every invocation or just specific APIs? does it return a value?)

More details about how to extend codegen in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#making-your-own-codegen-modules